# Examples of SNMP

Tags: snmp

I grasp a basic theoretical knowledge about SNMP. However, I saw several events from our SIEM showing that a client endpoint generated SNMP events with port 161 and concluding that this host could be a local UDP scanner or something like that.

How could this local machine trigger such SNMP logs, which I assumed that they should have come from servers or from admins? Did the user use any tool or appliance to implement this?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, and how your title question relates to the body question. SNMP is a simple, lightweight protocol that anything can generate. Not just servers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is nothing suspicious about SNMP running on a PC - it can be used on any network device. HP is one PC maker that includes SNMP for desktop PCs.

But secondly SNMP agents send messages called “traps” on port 162. Port 161 is used to manage SNMP. So your real question is, does the user of the PC have a legitimate reason to manage SNMP agents? That is what you must investigate next.

Comment: The user did not have the legitimate reason to manage SNMP agent since he was just a normal user. Can you give a more detailed example of SNMP agent management, which uses port 161?

Comment: Well, an SNMP management station would configure SNMP agents by sending packets on 161 and SNMP agents would report status back on port 162. That’s about it really, SNMP is a very simple protocol